# How do I pass one PHP url as a php variable in another URL without that syntax messing up the variables?

Tags: php

I have a download page that take arguments like the download URL, the download-counter data file url, and the page to return to after downloading.
It is arranged like so:

```
start.php?url=...&page=...&file=...
(Download url, redirect page, counter file)
```

The problem is, when the redirect page contains PHP arguments with ? and & symbols, the URL becomes a confusing mess for PHP to work with.

Example:

```
start.php?url=URLTEXT&page=page?test1=x&test2=xx&file=FILETEXT
```

What should happen:

```
url=URLTEXT
page=page?test1=x&test2=xx
file=FILETEXT
```

what happens:

```
url=URLTEXT
page=page?test1=x
test2=xx
file=FILETEXT
```

How could I substitute characters or somehow make these arguments pass correctly in php?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: How about using `urlencode` and `urldecode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure how your "messed up" URL looks like. However the string after the "?" is called Query String, and you can decode/encode it with

```
urlencode($normalString); //will be encoded for use in URL
urldeocde($queryString); //will be decoded for "normal" use
```

**EDIT:**

Here is some short example:

```
echo "Encode for use in URL: ";
echo urlencode("this is a string & üäöllasdlk<bbb2");
echo "<br />";

echo "Decode to use it in your script: ";
echo urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Output:

> Encode for use in URL:
>   this+is+a+string+%26+%C3%BC%C3%A4%C3%B6llasdlk%3Cbbb2 
>   Decode to use it in your script: test=12

(Assuming you have a Querystring containing the variable `test=12`)

Comment: I will try this, allow me a minute to test.
I messed up after the ?, sorry

Comment: This should work, to elaborate in your example the second `?` is being converted to a `&`. By using `urlencode()` it it should stay the same and be there when you `urldecode()`.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept if it's working for you! And get a cooler username :D

Comment: I can't upvote, but it about 3 seconds (When it lets me) I will except xD

Comment: Got a cooler username, btw.  I didn't even know I had an account.

Answer (score -3):

Just use htmlspecialchars function on your URL string:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php